# Power planes vs power tracks?

Tags: pcb-design

I'm working on a 4 layers project - 2 signal layers (top and bottom), one internal ground plane and a "mixed" power tracks and ground internal plane which is the object of the question and that you can see below with a power plane like this:

In red, 12V, green 3.3V, black is ground.

There are no particular requirements for currents, we can consider that all tracks power small consumption ICs. 0-50mA.

[image]

Do you see a particular reason for this design vs "real" power planes roughly like this? I kept some black ground copper because there's an antenna strip on top layer at this location (yellow on the drawing.)

[image]

Comment: What's the current rating/requirement for the 3.3v and 12v power rails?

Comment: If you have 4 layers, what are they used for? Usually two middle ones are power and ground layers and top and bottom layers are used for signals.

Comment: @AnantheshAcharya, I updated the question, no particular requirements 0-50mA

Comment: @Justme. top, bottom : signals, One inner for ground and the other one is the one that you can see on the drawings

Comment: For Antenna strip you can use coplanar waveguide routing technique. So that ground reference can be provided on the same layer.. in addition to providing the ground reference in the immediate next layer